# Adobe Edge Animate : How to get Symbol's current time?

Tags: adobe-edge

In Adobe Edge Animate, how to get Symbol's current time ?

I use a mix of jQuery & Adobe Edge codes to program my page. I want to check if a symbol's time stays at first frame (if in Flash's concept).

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) 
{
   var the_stage = $.Edge.getComposition("EDGE-123456").getStage();
   var sym = the_stage.getSymbol(id);
   // how to get current time ?
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found a solution. To get the current time, use:

```
var pos = sym.getPosition()
```

`pos` is an integer . If the symbol hasn't played before, its value is **-1**, else it is the position in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is ok, but need clarification.

If your animation is "inside" the div:

```
<div id="stage_animation_0" class="animation_0"></div>
```

I suggest to name class attribute with "animation_" + animation number and id attribute with "stage_" + class name.

## GET

You can obtain actual timeline position in this way:

```
var getAnimationPos = function(animation) {     
  var stage = $.Edge.getComposition(animation).getStage();
  var sym = stage.getSymbol("stage_" + animation);
  return sym.getPosition();
}
```

In this way you can obtain your timeline position with:

```
var position = getAnimationPos("animation_0");
```

## SET

Setting the actual timeline position is more "complicated".

If your animation is playing and you want to jump to a specific position:

```
var jumpPosition = 300; /* expressed in milliseconds */
$.Edge.getComposition(animation).getStage().play(jumpPosition);
```

If your animation is paused and you want to set position without play, you have to:

```
var jumpPosition = 300; /* expressed in milliseconds */
$.Edge.getComposition(animation).getStage().stop(jumpPosition);
```

In this way, when you'll call play(), animation will start from position 300.